# Unable to create associations using Apriori association rule algorithm for my dataset where the support is 0.01, confidence=0.8 and maxlen=10

Tags: r, data-mining, association-rules

Here's the code that I'm using:

library(arules)

library(arulesViz)

library(tidyverse)

library(readxl)

library(knitr)

library(ggplot2)

library(lubridate)

library(plyr)

library(dplyr)

tr <- read.transactions('D:/work/ML/Data/10OctMergedParts.csv', format = 'basket', sep=',')

association.rules <- apriori(tr, parameter = list(**supp=0.01,
conf=0.8,maxlen=10,maxtime = 0**))

summary(association.rules)

write(association.rules, file = "D:/work/ML/Data/DemoInputs/10OctAssoc_P_B_D_Support1ConfPoint8.csv", sep = ",")

print("----------DONE---------------")

The output I get is :

Parameter specification:
confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen

maxlen target  ext
0.8    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       0    0.01      1     10  rules TRUE

Algorithmic control:
filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 63

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].

set transactions ...[**958 item(s), 6371 transaction(s)**] done [0.01s].

sorting and recoding items ... [**242 item(s)**] done [0.00s].

creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].

checking subsets of size 1 2 3 4 5 6 7Error in apriori(tr, parameter =

list(supp = 0.01, conf = 0.8, maxlen = 10,  :
**not enough memory**. Increase minimum support!

When I run this with the sample dataset which is available online **'Online Retail.xlsx'**.
I can see that this gets executed without the out-of-memory error.

This is the result with the online data:

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].

set transactions ...[**7876 item(s), 22191 transaction(s)**] done [0.17s].

sorting and recoding items ... [**2324 item(s)**] done [0.01s].

creating transaction tree ... done [0.01s].

checking subsets of size 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 done [0.24s].

writing ... [49122 rule(s)] done [0.10s].

creating S4 object  ... done [0.04s].

I can see that the **number of items are much more in the online data** and the **transaction length is also much higher than the data I have**.
{**max transaction length in my data is 241** and that of the **online data is ~500**}

Please can someone help me understand why things are not working with my dataset?

Comment: This needs formating